# My boolean returns false to anything equal to or greater than 1000, why?

Tags: java, boolean

Here is the snippet of code that I am having an issue with:

```
            int inputIsInt = Integer.valueOf(JTextFieldName.getText());
            String format = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(inputIsInt);
            boolean isSame = format.equals(JTextFieldName.getText());
            if (isSame == true) {...
```

Comment: By the way, you can replace `if (isSame == true)` with `if (isSame)`

Answer (score 6):

Well the obvious next step of diagnostics is to print both of the formatted strings. I *suspect* you'll find it's the difference between "1,000" and "1000" - but that will depend on your locale.

The important thing to take away from this experience *isn't* to do with string formatting at all - it's about debugging and diagnostics:

- You could have logged both strings to determine the difference
- You could have written a short but complete program to show both values
- You could have used a debugger to examine the values while the program was executing
- You could have written a unit test

Make sure you understand all these options, and work out when to use which - it'll make you a much better developer, and allow you to solve future problems yourself. (I don't mind helping anyone, but it's generally quicker if you can help yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  I'm fairly new to porgramming and haven't learned anything about debugging or most of what you've written.  I did do a System.out.println(format); though and yes, it is 1,000 while my input is in the format of 1000. I will work on this next to see how I can get the format to change automatically when the [enter] key is used. Thanks again.